# Deleting a resource inside HTTP GET

Tags: rest, http

What are the implications of deleting a resource inside HTTP GET operation?
I know about REST standards and best practices, but what complications could arise from such an implementation?
Any example would be useful.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RESTful design principles, the HTTP GET method is supposed to be safe and idempotent, meaning it should not modify the state of the server and should produce the same result regardless of how many times it's called. Performing resource deletion within an HTTP GET operation is a violation of these principles and can lead to several complications:

**Violation of Idempotence:**
By definition, GET requests should be idempotent, meaning multiple identical requests should have the same effect as a single request. Deleting a resource within a GET operation is not idempotent and goes against this principle.

**Caching Issues:**
GET requests are often cached by intermediaries (like proxies or CDNs) to improve performance. If a GET request results in resource deletion, caching mechanisms may become inconsistent, leading to potential issues with stale data.

**Unintended Side Effects:**
Users and developers expect that a GET request won't cause any changes on the server side. If a GET operation deletes a resource, it can lead to unexpected side effects, such as data loss or disruption of other functionalities that depend on the existence of the resource.

**Security Concerns:**
From a security perspective, allowing resource deletion via GET can expose your application to various vulnerabilities. For example, malicious actors might trick users into clicking on a link that performs a destructive action without their explicit consent.

**Breaking Client Expectations:**
Clients (applications or users) interacting with your API or website will likely assume that GET requests are read-only operations. If you break this expectation, it could lead to confusion and compatibility issues with existing clients.

**Search Engine Crawlers:**
Search engines and web crawlers often make GET requests to index content. If resource deletion occurs in response to these requests, it could lead to unpredictable behavior in terms of search engine indexing and ranking.

**Non-Idempotent Operations:**
Deleting a resource is inherently a non-idempotent operation. Introducing non-idempotent operations within the GET method goes against REST principles and can complicate the predictability and reliability of your API.

**HTTP Method Semantics:**
Using the DELETE method explicitly conveys the intention to delete a resource. Mixing deletion semantics with the GET method can lead to confusion and a lack of clarity in the API design.

Answer (score 1):

> HTTP does not attempt to require the results of a GET to be safe.  What it does is require that the semantics of the operation be safe, and therefore it is a fault of the implementation, not the interface or the user of that interface, if anything happens as a result that causes loss of property -- [Fielding, 2002](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-tag/2002Apr/0207.html)

Loosely translated, if something goes expensively wrong because someone else believed that your server handled GET requests safely, when their lawyers are blaming you and your lawyers are blaming them... YOUR lawyers are going to be the ones having a bad time.

---

The kinds of things that can go wrong include some web crawler, like Google, enumerating all of the resource identifiers in your API, trying to GET the current representation of each so that it can index the results.  Or browsers trying to improve a humans usability experience by proactively fetching and caching resource representations to reduce observed latency.

And therefore you need to be thinking about things like "what are the consequences of unintentionally deleting resources?", and if they are bad then what additional countermeasures do you need to manage the risk.

In the common case, not doing unsafe things in your GET handlers is more cost effective than developing the countermeasures.